# Where do you manage web and worker roles in portal.azure.com?

Tags: azure, cloud, portal, azure-cloud-services

Where do you manage azure web and worker roles in the new portal (portal.azure.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, you don't. Cloud Services (web/worker roles) are not yet in the portal.azure.com site.

Comment: Thanks @mcollier. Do you know when this functionality will be implemented?

Comment: @Jacob - Nobody can publicly discuss plans around potential future features and related release dates. Note that portal.azure.com is still considered a *preview* and is evolving.

Comment: It's current #18 and "Under Review" on the Preview Portal [feedback site](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/5760807-cloud-service-new-portal).